# use object in foreach multiple times

Tags: c#, foreach

I am using a foreach loop to do a specific task per object. The problem is, that this sometimes fails, then it needs to be executed another time and so on. Is there any possibility to do the same task on the same object again?

To visualize this problem a little bit:

```
foreach (Foo obj in FooList)
{
     obj.DoSomething();
     obj.CheckIfSucceded();
}
```

Now if `CheckIfSucceded()` returns false, I want to use the same object in the loop again, instead of moving on to the next one.

Comment: Why don't you just use a standard for loop?

Comment: What is your condition for "stop trying"? Or it have to `Secceded`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're happy repeatedly trying the operation on the same object forever, you could do something like this:

```
foreach (Foo obj in FooList)
{
    do
    {
        obj.DoSomething();
    } while (!obj.CheckIfSucceded())
}
```

If you want to only try it for a set number of times, you can add a simple timeout:

```
foreach (Foo obj in FooList)
{
    int tries = 0;
    do
    {
        obj.DoSomething();
        tries++;
    } while (!obj.CheckIfSucceded() && tries < 5)
}
```

Alternatively, if you prefer using `while` to `do while`, you could do this:

```
foreach (Foo obj in FooList)
{
    int tries = 0;
    bool succeeded = false;
    while (!succeeded && tries < 5)
    {
        obj.DoSomething();
        succeeded = obj.CheckIfSucceded();
        tries++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
foreach (Foo obj in FooList)
{
    do 
    {
         obj.DoSomething();
    } while (!obj.CheckIfSucceded())
}
```

This is a perfect usecase for a [do while](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/370s1zax.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) loop.

Comment: Unless it never succeeds :)

Comment: @Kędzru Can you elaborate your comment? If the method "DoSomething" can change the state of the object I do not see the problem here.

Comment: @PawelMaga He means that you should have some kind of limit on the number of retries, in case some condition (which may be a bug) means that `CheckIfSucceeded()` always returns false.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yeah i understand that, nvm. It's hard to provide the correct answer without knowing the implementation of this object.

Answer (score 1):

```
int failCount = 0;
int maxFailCount = 10;
foreach (Foo obj in FooList)
{
     failCount = 0;
     obj.DoSomething();
     bool succeeded = obj.CheckIfSucceded();
     while(!succeeded && ++failCount <= maxFailCount)
     {
         obj.DoSomething();
         succeeded = obj.CheckIfSucceded();
     }
}
```

Here's a even more "complicated" approach that handles a maximum fail-count per run and in total which can be disabled:

```
int maxFailCount = 10;          
int maxTotalFailCount = 100;
bool checkFailCount = maxFailCount > 0;
bool checkTotalFailCount = maxTotalFailCount > 0;

int totalFailCount = 0;
foreach (Foo obj in FooList)
{
    int failCount = 0;
    bool breakLoop = false;
    bool retry = true;
    while (retry)
    {
        obj.DoSomething();
        bool succeeded = obj.CheckIfSucceded();
        if (!succeeded)
        {
            if (checkTotalFailCount && ++totalFailCount > maxTotalFailCount)
            {
                breakLoop = true;
                retry = false;
            }
            else if (checkFailCount && ++failCount > maxFailCount)
            {
                retry = false;   
            }
        }
    }
    if (breakLoop)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Set `failCount` back to 0 within the loop? (I can see it being done either way - depends on whether `maxFailCount` is a maximum for the entire set or a maximum for each object) (Not my downvote)

Comment: Why are the calls and checks in there twice? Unless I'm missing something it seems needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Other idea would be to 'implement your own `foreach`' :

```
        var enumerator = FooList.GetEnumerator();

        enumerator.MoveNext();

        while (enumerator.Current != null)
        {
            enumerator.Current.DoSomething();
            if(!enumerator.Current.CheckIfSucceded()) continue;
            enumerator.MoveNext();
        }
```

This way you can use just one `while` loop and control when to move to the next object inside this loop (something that is not possible with regular `foreach` loop)...